# How to register server start listener in wildly

Tags: wildfly

I want to perform some operation after wildly server has started. Is there any listener available in wildly server which will be invoked after server start?

Comment: Have you deployed a web application to the server?

Comment: You can use DMR API's or JBoss CLI command to check if server is started or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `@Startup` bean:

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class StartupBean {

  @PostConstruct
  void postConstruct {
    //your code
  }
  ...
}
```

More information can be found [here](http://www.mastertheboss.com/javaee/ejb-3/how-to-create-an-ejb-startup-service).